# python manage.py shell won't open anymore: NameError: name 'Posts' is not defined

Tags: python, django, class, shell, models

Weird problem in the Django shell, with Python.

I had a class in my `models.py` file called `Posts`. I decided the name was better as `Post` so I changed the name in the file, and tried

`python manage.py syncdb`

to sync the changes but I got an error: `NameError: name 'Posts' is not defined`

Then I tried to launch the shell with `python manage.py shell` but got the same error.

I went back to the `models.py` file and changed the name of the class back to `Posts`. I tried to run the shell again and this time it worked.

So my question is not really how to get around the error, since I've got that now. But my problem now is how do I change the name of a class in models?

Answer (score 2):

You can always change the name of the class, so long as you update everywhere that references that class.

You may need to set the Meta option [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) to ensure that installations continue to refer to the correct table.

On another note, generally singular names for model classes are preferred (so "Post" is better than "Posts").

Answer (score 1):

The current recommended way is to use [Django South](http://south.aeracode.org/). Any changes to your models need corresponding schema changes to the database. This is not easy to perform especially without loss of data. South is highly recommended for all django development. In fact, its functionality is planned to be merged into the next version of Django.